# Target reference line in combination chart

Tags: spotfire

I have a combination chart with same type of values on both left y-axis scale and right y-axis scale. When I add a target reference line using lines and curves at some point on y-axis scale, I see two reference lines one for left y axis and the other for right y axis. Is there any option to display only one reference line according to scale on my left y-axis ? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes but you have asked a few questions on StackOverflow and people have answered them and you haven't rewarded them I'd read this first: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Comment: can the reference line be displayed only once according to the scale on my left y-axis

Comment: yes, use the FIRST() aggregation method. If you'd like, post some sample data so people can test

Comment: data is same as that of present here - http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13306216   I have created combination chart out of it and I have monthyear column on my x-axis, percentage on left y-axis and count on right y-axis. Custome expression used on y-axis is Sum([columnA]) / Count([columnB]), Sum([columnC]). I should display reference line only for left y-axis scale. could you please elabarate how can I make use of first() function. Thanks a lot, your inputs really helped me till now :)

Answer (score 1):

the way I understand your question is that you...

- have a combination chart with *multiple axes*
- are attempting to use the Lines and Curves feature to create a line based on your data
- have one line appearing for each axis
- **would like to have only one line for the entire chart**

the short answer is, unfortunately **this is not possible when using multiple axes**.

I assume that what you are trying to compare is two relative sets of values on different axes, but one of those sets has some kind of benchmark (target reference line) to measure against.

I can suggest two possible workarounds that might still do what you need:

1. if your benchmark value never changes, you can add a horizontal line with a fixed value. technically, this will draw as many lines as you have axes, but since they will all be the same value, they'll render on top of one another and appear to be the same line.
2. if the benchmark does change, and you can get the benchmark into a Document Property, you can render it just like the above, but based on the property rather than a fixed value. this would allow the value to be dynamic, but you have to get it in there in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. range on both axes is not same. And due to this I will definitely see two lines. And also I observe that I cannot change my line color and option is disabled while using multiple axis. Is there any other way like iron python script to display only one line with customized color we need.